# nodejs http request post _http_outgoing type error

Tags: node.js, http

Environment: node: v4.5.0  os: windows 7 64bit.

Hi everyone, When I use http to post a request to a website, I received Error.

I have searched many answers and tryed these, but the error still persist. What could I do?
Here is error message:

```
_http_outgoing.js:351
throw new TypeError('The header content contains invalid characters');
TypeError: The header content contains invalid characters
 at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:351:13)
 at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:79:14)
 at Object.exports.request (http.js:31:10)
 at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\http.js:30:16)
 at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
 at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
 at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
```

Here is my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var postData = querystring.stringify({
    'content': 'abc',
    'mid': 8837
});

var options = {
    hostname: 'www.imooc.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/course/docomment',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept':'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language':'en,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.6',
        'Connection':'keep-alive',
        'Content-Length':postData.length,
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'Cookie':'imooc_uuid=e9896052-b2fb-4b23-85e8-74673c7ac165; imooc_isnew_ct=1476177989; loginstate=1; apsid=lhNTQ3NDk4OWFjZDBiNTFmODBjMmNkNDRmY2NjMmUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMjEzMzI0NAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAxMDI3MTkxNDkzQHFxLmNvbQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADY1NTdiODMyZmM5NDMzZWNjYzg2ZGRjNDc5YzU3NTA2VrD8V1aw%2FFc%3DNz; last_login_username=1027191493%40qq.com; PHPSESSID=0ib2e90urbk47po8su89tvks13; IMCDNS=0; jwplayer.qualityLabel=è?????; jwplayer.volume=100; Hm_lvt_f0cfcccd7b1393990c78efdeebff3968=1476346029,1476363725,1476416065,1476448867; Hm_lpvt_f0cfcccd7b1393990c78efdeebff3968=1476459900; imooc_isnew=2; cvde=5800d25c99f68-52',
        'Host':'www.imooc.com',
        'Origin':'http://www.imooc.com',
        'Referer':'http://www.imooc.com/video/8837',
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
}

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        console.log('status:' + res.statusCode);
        console.log('headers:' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log(Buffer.isBuffer(chunk));
            console.log(typeof chunk);
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            console.log('评论完毕');
        });

        res.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log('error:' + e.message);
        });
})

req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You dont need all that headers, try to remove them all, most of them used by browser

Comment: Thanks.
Because you reminded me of headers, I removed part headers, just retained Accept、Content-Type、Referer、Content-Length、Cookie, but the error still persist. Than I checked the value of Cookie
'Cookie':'jwplayer.qualityLabel=è?????; jwplayer.volume=100', I found the value of jwplayer.qualityLabel contains invalid characters, removed it.   Everything is beautiful .